# Adding Graphics to a Tyre

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Blender noob here!

I followed this tutorial to model a tyre (in my case a bike tyre without the rim):
https://youtu.be/a90cYLEbpi4

I'm really pleased with how it's looking and now I want to add some graphics to the sidewall of the tyre. The tyre has a sub-div and solidify modifier (not applied). Here is where I'm pulling my hair out after watching a load of tutorials! I've tried adding the image as a plane, sub dividing and shrink wrapping but this looks like the graphic is pinched and still appears to be floating above the surface (despite playing with the offset setting of the shrink wrap modifier).

I've tried creating UV maps of the whole tyre or part of the tyre, but the graphic does not appear in the UV editor window in the shading tab to edit a UV Map over / does not project onto the surface – or if I add the graphic using nodes it just repeats all over the tyre rather than just the sidewall of the UV map I created. Also, it alters the colour of the tyre from the desired dark grey to black.

Here's a screenshot of where I'm at with a UV map of the whole tyre side wall and a flat graphic of where I'm trying to get to. Hopefully you guys can help! Thanks!

[image: Screen Grab]

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: Hello :). Just a blind guess - The UV editor seems to be pinned (white pin). Perhaps that's why other no other UVs are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this which helped solve my problem, along with correctly unwrapping my objects mesh:

[Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Comment: mark your answer as solved...